# Area of a 2D convex hull

Tags: code-golf, number, geometry, integer

You are given an array/list/vector of pairs of integers representing cartesian coordinates \$(x, y)\$ of points on a 2D Euclidean plane; all coordinates are between \$−10^4\$ and \$10^4\$, duplicates are allowed. Find the area of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of those points, rounded to the nearest integer; an exact midpoint should be rounded to the closest even integer. You may use floating-point numbers in intermediate computations, but only if you can guarantee that the final result will be always correct. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest correct program wins.

The *convex hull* of a set of points \$P\$ is the smallest convex set that contains \$P\$. On the Euclidean plane, for any single point \$(x,y)\$, it is the point itself; for two distinct points, it is the line containing them, for three non-collinear points, it is the triangle that they form, and so forth.

A good visual explanation of what a convex hulls, is best described as imagining all points as nails in a wooden board, and then stretching a rubber band around them to enclose all the points:
[image]

Some test cases:

```
Input: [[50, -13]]
Result: 0

Input: [[-25, -26], [34, -27]]
Result: 0

Input: [[-6, -14], [-48, -45], [21, 25]]
Result: 400

Input: [[4, 30], [5, 37], [-18, 49], [-9, -2]]
Result: 562

Input: [[0, 16], [24, 18], [-43, 36], [39, -29], [3, -38]]
Result: 2978

Input: [[19, -19], [15, 5], [-16, -41], [6, -25], [-42, 1], [12, 19]]
Result: 2118

Input: [[-23, 13], [-13, 13], [-6, -7], [22, 41], [-26, 50], [12, -12], [-23, -7]]
Result: 2307

Input: [[31, -19], [-41, -41], [25, 34], [29, -1], [42, -42], [-34, 32], [19, 33], [40, 39]]
Result: 6037

Input: [[47, 1], [-22, 24], [36, 38], [-17, 4], [41, -3], [-13, 15], [-36, -40], [-13, 35], [-25, 22]]
Result: 3908

Input: [[29, -19], [18, 9], [30, -46], [15, 20], [24, -4], [5, 19], [-44, 4], [-20, -8], [-16, 34], [17, -36]]
Result: 2905
```

Comment: Do you have any test cases?

Comment: Not counting whitespace in code golf is a bad idea, it leads to submissions with massive strings of whitespace plus generic code to convert the string to code and execute it.

Comment: So if someone can just make a whitespace solution...

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126336/what-is-the-area-of-this-polygon)

Comment: _an exact midpoint should be rounded to the closest even integer_: just wondering what's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @Arnauld Round-to-even is the [default rounding mode](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcEmN7EkQy/DjgshUlySkpkPEsrMK1HITczM09BUqObiLCgC8tM0lFTTFFTTYvKUdBRAAhrGeqaaUKYJkKlpzVX7//@/5LScxPTi/7o5uQA) on IEEE 754 systems. Java and JavaScript mandate rounding towards positive infinity, though.

Comment: @nwellnhof True. But enforcing this rule is just an annoyance for languages that don't do it that way (and I think Python 2 doesn't round-to-even either). I don't think we should round at all anyway. The triangle `[[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]` really should yield \$1/2\$ rather than \$0\$.

Comment: Usually challenges are self-contained, but this one isn't. Could you explain what a convex hull is, and how to compute it? Or point to some reference online resource?

Comment: I've VTCed as unclear until @OlivierGrégoire's comment is addressed. Ping me when it is and I'll retract my vote or vote to reopen.

Answer (score 9):

## SQL Server 2012+, 84 bytes

```
SELECT Round(Geometry::ConvexHullAggregate(Geometry::Point(x,y,0)).STArea(),0)FROM A
```

Makes use of the geometry functions and aggregates in SQL Server.
Coordindates are from table `A` with columns `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 9):

## Java 10, <s>405</s> <s>...didn't fit anymore; see edit history..</s> <s>317</s> 316 bytes

```java
P->{int n=P.length,l=0,i=0,p,q,t[],h[][]=P.clone(),s=0;for(;++i<n;)l=P[i][0]<P[l][0]?i:l;p=l;do for(h[s++]=P[p],q=-~p%n,i=-1;++i<n;q=(t[1]-P[p][1])*(P[q][0]-t[0])<(t[0]-P[p][0])*(P[q][1]-t[1])?i:q)t=P[i];while((p=q)!=l);for(p=i=0;i<s;p-=(t[0]+h[++i%s][0])*(t[1]-h[i%s][1]))t=h[i];return Math.round(.5*p/~(p%=2))*~p;}
```

-52 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*
-3 bytes thanks to *@PeterTaylor*
-7 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVPLcptAELzrKzYHV@1as4R9oEcQyRfEpSofKR2IhAUOXiFAdqVU@NeVmQX7A/BBzDKz9HT3jJ6z10w@H/7e9lXWtux3VrrrjLHSdXnzlO1z9kCvjFUnd2R7jvl0l@7YVsSY7mf4eGCOJey2lT@vWGUu2QZV7o5dAVUSQom/Gs6An0FBn2J5j2A5F9AmYfx0ang8n5cbF4sq2ablLg13m21aUfxV/qjiOqniw4nRxSJt53NESOsdnBP5Xt85bCDVCHBOeJeqnaQ6RnHPt@mZcGSHD7HhFIZq@FlVVMXL2OssOs8gfivKKue8Ts7iW1IJT7JOUEpcbtq4lolHmhcp9r1rRzTfukh9AvEQqyCsJu8ujUNjuyJoThd34EF0X39/5/VdooW4f6/j/hZ7jxnDUF/@VOWetV3WYXg9lQf2gkPhj11TuiNanzXHVgxDefzXdvlLcLp0QY3VrnLc5W9@iFwELtj713Fm12sUglSm74WIp3wudQRSL3q4GouH5WSgEEIEUaD8M5xOaIF6LIJIuwJpIzxpBTqaDGjBELMIzJJQ1Qrsmg5rlPsFtYo80xbUynM1YLyJhErwBqRZTYZXCKMIRkUQedboiiVrMWqfsXqwGsP6C9M3gMtDDT4O2IB80hp8P9wNiMKhkVTaZwxdmdrSqFEa6hk14Qoamrgm1RhRGsqjK7iThg7ohyF2NgQzXa1dwiBJg6Z@ZgHGT08tgd6J0KcZ3mRDtodjyvgUktXT90Z/DnYFfk3w32sXw6B1OGyUtH5dR5OspyY1XlyNm@DNQs5I74NIP@vZ7T8)

[Or **299 bytes without rounding..**](https://tio.run/##pVPbcpswEH3PV6gPmYF65eqGL5Vpv6AZz@SR4YHaxJASGQN2puOhv@7uCuIPIA/WCq109pyz69fskvHX/Z/brsralv3KSnd9YKx0Xd68ZLucPdEnY/vj@XeVs12AmSRNUrYNLSb6B1yemGMxu235jytmmYu38yp3h66AKhZQ4q@GE@AzKOgppnfV0eVBCG0s7MuxCexsVm6cDat4m5RpItLNNqko/iy/V7aOK7s/MrpYJO1shghJncIp5v/qR4cFuBwBTnHQJTLllMcYfg22yYlweIdLuAkoDFlxz0rK4mWsdQo7z8C@F2WVB0Edn8IvcRXaS9awLBZ7zxYV2XLT2ozHHnBWJFj@sR1BPYMi8QcIi5AFQTZ5d24cy74p29@sN5UxDDUaW@5Y22Udhsux3LM37ELw3DWlO6DTWXNow6ELz3/bLn@bH8/dvMZsV7nA5e@@a0E4d/Od/xxbdL1GArjUfR@GdspzriLgatHDVRvcLCcDCRAIIkH6VUwntEA9BkG4WQE3Ee6UBBVNBjSgiVkEekmocgVmTZs1yv2EWkmeKQNy5blq0N5EQiV4DVyvJsNLhJEEIyOIPGt0xZC1GJU/MWqwGsP6E93XgMNDBT42WIB8Ugp8PZwNiMRQiEvlTzRdmVpSy1Ea6hk14Qhq6rgi1RhRGsqjKziTmjbohyZ2RoCertYsYZCkQFE9vQDtuyeXQN9E6G6GN1mT7WI80v4Iyarpc6PujV2BHxP895rF0Gglhonixo/raJLx1LjCi6txErxZyBnpfRDpH3p2@w8).

**Explanation:**

There are three steps to do:

1. Calculate the points for the Convex Hull based on the input-coordinates (using [Jarvis' Algorithm/Wrapping](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-1-jarviss-algorithm-or-wrapping/))
2. Calculate the area of this Convex Hull
3. Banker's rounding..

To calculate the coordinates that are part of the Convex Hull, we use the following approach:

Set point \$l\$ and \$p\$ to the left-most coordinate. Then calculate the next point \$p\$ in a counterclockwise rotation; and continue doing so until we've reached back at the initial point \$l\$. Here a visual for this:

[image]

As for the code:

```java
P->{                      // Method with 2D integer array as parameter & long return-type
  int n=P.length,         //  Integer `n`, the amount of points in the input
      l=0,                //  Integer `l`, to calculate the left-most point
      i=0,                //  Index-integer `i`
      p,                  //  Integer `p`, which will be every next counterclockwise point
      q,                  //  Temp integer `q`
      t[],                //  Temp integer-array/point
      h[][]=P.clone(),    //  Initialize an array of points `h` for the Convex Hull
      s=0;                //  And a size-integer for this Convex Hull array, starting at 0
  for(;++i<n;)            //  Loop `i` in the range [1, `n`):
    l=                    //   Change `l` to:
      P[i][0]<P[l][0]?    //   If i.x is smaller than l.x:
       i                  //    Replace `l` with the current `i`
      :l;                 //   Else: leave `l` unchanged
  p=l;                    //  Now set `p` to this left-most coordinate `l`
  do                      //  Do:
    for(h[s++]=P[p],      //   Add the `p`'th point to the 2D-array `h`
        q=-~p%n,          //   Set `q` to `(p+1)` modulo-`n`
        i=-1;++i<n;       //    Loop `i` in the range [0, `n`):
        ;q=               //      After every iteration: change `q` to:
                          //       We calculate: (i.y-p.y)*(q.x-i.x)-(i.x-p.x)*(q.y-i.y), 
                          //       which results in 0 if the three points are collinear;
                          //       a positive value if they are clockwise;
                          //       or a negative value if they are counterclockwise
           (t[1]-P[p][1])*(P[q][0]-t[0])<(t[0]-P[p][0])*(P[q][1]-t[1])?
                          //       So if the three points are counterclockwise:
            i             //        Replace `q` with `i`
           :q)            //       Else: leave `q` unchanged
      t=P[i];             //     Set `t` to the `i`'th Point (to save bytes)
  while((p=q)             //  And after every while-iteration: replace `p` with `q`
             !=l);        //  Continue the do-while as long as `p` is not back at the
                          //  left-most point `l` yet
  // Now step 1 is complete, and we have our Convex Hull points in the List `h`
                  
  for(p=i=0;              //  Set `p` (the area) to 0
      i<s                 //  Loop `i` in the range [0, `s`):
      ;p-=                //    After every iteration: Decrease the area `p` by:
        (t[0]+h[++i%s][0])//     i.x+(i+1).x
        *(t[1]-h[i%s][1]))//     Multiplied by i.y-(i+1).y
    t=h[i];               //   Set `t` to the `i`'th point (to save bytes)
 return Math.round(.5*p/~(p%=2))*~p;}
                          //  And return `p/2` rounded to integer with half-even
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92471/discussion-between-kevin-cruijssen-and-olivier-gregoire).

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
Round@*Area@*ConvexHullMesh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVK5asNQEOz9FaqNHtYeugqDQpo0gZA/EImMDbYMjhwC4n27soekuEs3Hs3Ozs7zpR2O3aUdTh/tdNhP79d7/9lsn25d22yfr/139/NyP59fu6/j9HY79cOuOeyacTOOeZYmASjGVH4EzOUXFjFNRmKF5X8fCh1n5QNXgjlXjJAmmLtE5JQpKRZUmhJEybXBWs1cKEnANqCMQOWeJEO@1pQ2JFygyodAaTAaZEHu/pqKQbEidJZRbE2ooF4uEze538b@oI5ZVhStO8n54p8tBgHQWTKpmRGsYWT9mkHLI@sILa0iDSOJTKqNkkG9hiwBSxs0Z@RyDh40DZoTSRjyjkA@G2crH07xs8nKyFaanNZQODePDyXK03jJ@sfgYikWs@VlAs@PuRzK8/qAOlKtL@AnazrJEOMmTr8)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>191</s>  189 bytes

Implements the [Jarvis march](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) (aka gift wrapping algorithm).

```javascript
P=>(r=(g=p=>([X,Y]=P[p],Y*h-X*v)+(P.map(([x,y],i)=>q=(y-Y)*(P[q][0]-x)<(x-X)*(P[q][1]-y)?i:q,q=P[++p]?p:0,h=X,v=Y)|q?g(q):V*h-H*v))(v=h=0,([[H,V]]=P.sort(([x],[X])=>x-X)))/2)+(r%1&&r&1)/2|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLbiIxELzvV8xlkQ02@DUvtA7XHDlFgywfUDYBoiTzIEIg5d/ZbpuZRDurvdX0VFdVd/tle9oeH7tD88Hf699P12d7Xds70lmysw0AV7GNt2vXeLaZ7nk1PdEZWc/ftg0h7swunh2ovWstufANnZK1a70Tnp/pL3LmVV@Rnl/o6rBsWQtas1njV81SsL2t2Mlu6Ge72pGWLh/A4R4cKDnZvRWMOHfPHjz4z49194GOnrnKgyOKU7pQkKb7KSeTbiLh61NcH@v3Y/36NH@td@QZBFLBEi6195Qmi0UifvxN4CoFhso8S5w2CPP/kDNUM8jlpgBsUsRKskSlfZsR40YQ1gKpYKbz0C@h35QBlmjbt6eZGrXDEDIkVCAki@ivQSrGDv1BCmpcF72UKvNipCWRLQNbQpo0hsHBjESMSMWqUeAWiAjKQVbK4h97BG9YdFD7gqgW5lUgEQ1g2WArel0uVazqQO09tMhHHloO0SHskBgvqMNRVJgNEUaH/IGKZ9UB4uw6BDOwUj1MlAk9djP5bXqO2VUw0BBdx/1L@B1qIcm3wePudNioGMo6ljGrGm6tSzHepPp2IHgj8a74jE3WH02J/jFwc3tV/VrMLRVX2FIM140LwtAQ7euBiPT6Bw)

Or [**170 bytes**](https://tio.run/##fVJNb@owELy/X5GjDTbYXucL1eXaI6cqKPIB9QN46muSUiGQ@t95uzZJq6bqJRptZmdmd/13c9wcHt727bt8bR6fLs/usnK3bOta/NaVWHu3qlsv1pOdrCZHPmWr2b9Ny1h9Emcv9tzddo6d5ZpP2KrufK28PPEbdpJVX9Fenvlyv@hEh1rTaeuX7UKJnavE0a35R7fcso4v7tHhDh04O7qdU4LV9Z249@g/OzRv7@ToRV15dCRxzufm8tC8HpqXp9lLs2XP2JAqkUgN3nOezOeJ@vOdIE2KDJN5kdRgCea/kDNSs8SVtkBsU8JGi8SkfZtV40YUBkVUNIM89Gvst2WAJdn27WlmRu04hA4JDQrpIvoDSsXYoT9IYU1C0UuZMi9GWprYOrA1pkljGBrMasKETKxag26BSKAcZLUuftgjeuOig9onJLUwr0GJaIDLRlvV60ptYhUCtfcAlY88QA/RMeyQmC4I4SgmzEaIomP@QKWzQoA0O4RgFlcKw0SZgrGbza/TS8puggFgdIj71/g71EKSL4PH3UHYqBrKEMuU1Qy3hlKNN2m@HAjfSLwrPWOb9Uczqn8M0l5fVb8We00lDbUUw3Xjgig0Rvt8ICq9/Ac) without the cumbersome rounding scheme.

Comment: Rounding was just a red herring because twice the area is always exactly integer.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Out of curiosity: if you knew rounding was a red herring, then why add it to distract from the otherwise good challenge?.. Not all languages have builtin Banker's rounding, not even well-known languages like JS and Java apparently. I like the challenge in general and enjoyed writing my Java answer, but the rounding and lack of explanation what Convex Hull is to make the challenge self-contained refrained me from upvoting it, tbh.. PS: Sorry _@Arnauld_ to do this as a comment in your answer..

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>85</s> <s>81</s> 78 bytes

```r
function(i,h=chull(i),j=c(h,h[1]))round((i[h,1]+i[j[-1],1])%*%diff(-i[j,2])/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLNTsMwEITv@xRREVICNnh3nT@JXHmJqgdoGyWoKqi0Em9fZp2Ga8sldix79pudPZz77MWf@9N@fRw/9/nohm49nHa7fCzcR7fOBzcseVUUh8/TfpPn43JwvHoclx9Lzytsi/uH@83Y97nHmZNV8SzFuc8P27fN0/HtfbfNh@7VfW@/uoVbuOP259gtqAwu86y0KIrsLgtE1x54KfFCKtJoa/2Pl5WViuRjg00sSdhlUl4EYrhBAiU1EAC0Js@QiS351jguKmUl11VgmSsSiHEDGoUc7CSZlvDntbnISVs31/XYnnJLDLASXOYzMtkCez4KChHbt511mZtbWg0YZIN8ptUUaxIoQR4ZoFxIwp5luu3nPERDfb2C8kQO3InZwtVIkhyRkQOfvGWtkoyqUkQDdbZSBb2hUKytB97QJZKCHD32jNNIqfbsEv3S1L8wHWg5TZzMCWsbbmidzJFgRpCpDXmsUkASUvI@2hgl69EgvNidZkoPHTA0kPzNQSjPvw)

Takes input as a 2-column matrix - first for `x`, second for `y`. R's `round` actually uses banker's rounding method, so we are quite lucky here.

The code uses a built-in function to determine, which points form the convex hull, and then applies the standard formula \$\sum_{i}{(x_{i-1}+x)\cdot(y_{i-1}-y_i)}/2\$ to get the polygon surface area.

Thanks to Giuseppe for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [R + sp package], 55 bytes

```r
function(x)round(sp::Polygon(x[chull(x),,drop=F])@area)
```

[Try it at RDRR](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(x)round(sp%3A%3APolygon(x%5Bchull(x)%2C%2Cdrop%3DF%5D)%40area)%0Af(rbind(c(-25%2C%20-26)))%0Af(rbind(c(-25%2C%20-26)%2C%20c(34%2C%20-27)))%0Af(rbind(c(-6%2C%20-14)%2C%20c(-48%2C%20-45)%2C%20c(21%2C%2025)))%0Af(rbind(c(4%2C%2030)%2C%20c(5%2C%2037)%2C%20c(-18%2C%2049)%2C%20c(-9%2C%20-2)))%0Af(rbind(c(0%2C%2016)%2C%20c(24%2C%2018)%2C%20c(-43%2C%2036)%2C%20c(39%2C%20-29)%2C%20c(3%2C%20-38)))%0Af(rbind(c(19%2C%20-19)%2C%20c(15%2C%205)%2C%20c(-16%2C%20-41)%2C%20c(6%2C%20-25)%2C%20c(-42%2C%201)%2C%20c(12%2C%2019)))%0Af(rbind(c(-23%2C%2013)%2C%20c(-13%2C%2013)%2C%20c(-6%2C%20-7)%2C%20c(22%2C%2041)%2C%20c(-26%2C%2050)%2C%20c(12%2C%20-12)%2C%20c(-23%2C%20-7)))%0Af(rbind(c(31%2C%20-19)%2C%20c(-41%2C%20-41)%2C%20c(25%2C%2034)%2C%20c(29%2C%20-1)%2C%20c(42%2C%20-42)%2C%20c(-34%2C%2032)%2C%20c(19%2C%2033)%2C%20c(40%2C%2039)))%0Af(rbind(c(47%2C%201)%2C%20c(-22%2C%2024)%2C%20c(36%2C%2038)%2C%20c(-17%2C%204)%2C%20c(41%2C%20-3)%2C%20c(-13%2C%2015)%2C%20c(-36%2C%20-40)%2C%20c(-13%2C%2035)%2C%20c(-25%2C%2022)))%0Af(rbind(c(29%2C%20-19)%2C%20c(18%2C%209)%2C%20c(30%2C%20-46)%2C%20c(15%2C%2020)%2C%20c(24%2C%20-4)%2C%20c(5%2C%2019)%2C%20c(-44%2C%204)%2C%20c(-20%2C%20-8)%2C%20c(-16%2C%2034)%2C%20c(17%2C%20-36))))

A function which takes a n x 2 matrix and returns the rounded area. This uses the `sp` package. The `drop=F` is needed to handle the one co-ordinate case. RDRR used for demo since TIO lacks the `sp` package.