# Golf the smallest circle!

Tags: code-golf, geometry

### The problem:

Given a non-empty set of points in the Cartesian plane, find the smallest circle that encloses them all ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)).

This problem is trivial if the number of points is three or less (if there's one point, the circle has a radius of zero; if there are two points, the line segment that joins the points is the diameter of the circle; if there are three (non-colinear) points, it's possible to get the equation of a circle that touches them all if they form a non-obtuse triangle, or a circle that touches only two points and encloses the third if the triangle is obtuse). So, for the sake of this challenge, the number of points should be greater than three.

### The challenge:

- **Input:** A list of 4 or more non-colinear points. The points should have X and Y coordinates; coordinates can be floats. To ease the challenge, no two points should share the same X coordinate.
  For example: `[(0,0), (2,1), (5,3), (-1,-1)]`
- **Output:** A tuple of values, `(h,k,r)`, such that \$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2\$ is the equation of the smallest circle that encloses all points.

### Rules:

- You can choose whatever input method suits your program.
- Output should be printed to `STDOUT` or returned by a function.
- "Normal", general-purpose, languages are preferred, but any esolang is acceptable.
- You can assume that the points are not colinear.
- This is code-golf, so the smallest program in bytes wins. The winner will be selected one week after the challenge is posted.

  - Please include the language you used and the length in bytes as header in the first line of your answer: `# Language: n bytes`

### Test cases:

- 1:

  - Input: `[(-8,0), (3,1), (-6.2,-8), (3,9.5)]`
  - Output: `[-1.6, 0.75, 9.89]`
- 2:

  - Input: `[(7.1,-6.9), (-7,-9), (5,10), (-9.5,-8)]`
  - Output: `[-1.73, 0.58, 11.58]`
- 3:

  - Input: `[(0,0), (1,2), (3,-4), (4,-5), (10,-10)]`
  - Output: `[5.5, -4, 7.5]`
- 4:

  - Input: `[(6,6), (-6,7), (-7,-6), (6,-8)]`
  - Output: `[0, -0.5, 9.60]`

Happy golfing!!!

---

### Related challenge:

- [Area of a 2D convex hull](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183191/area-of-a-2d-convex-hull/)

Comment: [Link to sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17807#17807)

Comment: “if there are three (non co-linear) points, it's possible to get the equation of a circle that touches them all”—but that may not be the smallest enclosing circle. For the three vertices of an obtuse triangle, the smallest enclosing circle is the one whose diameter is the longest side.

Comment: @Arnauld Same as you. For test case 2, I get center (-1.73, 0.58) and for test case 3 (5.5, -4).

Comment: @Arnauld thanks for your comment. I have edited the post accordingly

Comment: @Arnauld oops, sorry. Indeed. Aldo, correcting with your observations

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
#~BoundingRegion~"MinDisk"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7nOKb80LyUzLz0oNT0zP69OyTczzyWzOFtJ7X9AUWZeSXRadHW1roWOQa2OQrWxjiGI0jXTM9LRtYCIWOqZ1tbGxnIhVJvrGeoAlViClZrr6IIZpjqGYCN0gepBelG1GEDMN9QxghiqawKiTXR0TcHCBjq6QN2oWsx0zCBu0TGHWQQWMIOa/h8A)

Built-ins are handy here. Output is a disk object with the centre and radius. Like others, I’ve found the 2nd and 3rd test cases to be different to the question.

Thanks to @lirtosiast for saving a byte!

If a list is required as output, [this can be done in 35 bytes (at the cost of an additional 8 bytes)](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoJAEIbvPUUYdJoR19xVD4FF1yC6igfJ1ZZwlbLToq@@rbtFeJrh5/v@mbYc7rwtB3Erdb3Xh77nssqyzXTs3rISsrnyRnRy8s5CnsTr4W315SnkkNe5UphAMMJa7YDMA5kfAiYuSX06jkWx@tOxT8AgqUVjQLtQILYCDT@7SyVw/QRCV4rRPCNAauMA0NhLhQFzv0D8O2QD9m3XHw). Thanks to @Roman for pointing this out.

Comment: I was expecting a Mathematica built-in. But I wasn't expecting Mathematica to have "disk objects".

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5NC4JAFEX3/YowaHWfOKYzuggs2gbRVlxIfjSEo5StxN8@6UwRrt7jcs59r8n7e9nkvbzlutrrQ9eVqkiSY/tWhVT1taxlq9INnLNUJ/l6ONlWX55S9WmVDgNF8Eashx3YPIi7PiiySeyG45hlqz8tXIYJiQ0qQGYJwUwFTfzsLhXP9jP4tpSCeQag0MQeaLKXCge3v0D8DpmAf9v1Bw) to get the output format right: `Append@@BoundingRegion[#,"MinDisk"]&`

Comment: 13.3 adds the built-in [`CircumscribedBall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircumscribedBall.html)

Answer (score 21):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>298 ... 243</s>  242 bytes

Returns an array `[x, y, r]`.

```javascript
p=>p.map(m=([c,C])=>p.map(([b,B])=>p.map(([a,A])=>p.some(([x,y])=>H(x-X,y-Y)>r,F=s=>Y=(d?((a*a+A*A-q)*j+(b*b+B*B-q)*k)/d:s)/2,d=c*(A-B)+a*(j=B-C)+b*(k=C-A),r=H(a-F(a+b),A-F(A+B,X=Y,j=c-b,k=a-c)))|r>m?0:o=[X,Y,m=r]),q=c*c+C*C),H=Math.hypot)&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/JbsJADL3zFTkhe2JPIS3QVnKqJBLi0jsoymGydIGmkyYRAqn/TrMI0ZP9nt8i783RNFn9WbX8bfPi8iaXSvxKl6aCUiDOKErwSkCcUvgfGgpG2Niy6PCJzj3ewIm3dOYd@jWtpRF/J5C/ABhl3EAF/INq70KqUjdUYY8OeJc/N3jnUS6ZgoBDdI2CvYQcoZsqOEjEAVItGzC8BuOmSEG3BG5IW9nRXjJO6SCGM0T8rf3yZfZsJd7SjkqpE6SfLjhzIxUhbeTVtB/641zZFqdTe2mLpnXEMY74Tma/G/tV6C/7DlrrNzA4fHvsj0fd2vXnqcjB62omk94IccyPNEvIie9p3g9eao/4cWSe9CJJ8Kpc6Tl156dBtiIelgXNBzt32t53k8/G3Dl5Yxg/9POBeDHQM@LOeZMvaTn20@paMBDLMfXyBw)

or [see a formatted version](https://tio.run/##bVLBbtpAEL37K94p2m1nt0ADJJWgAkuIS@9Blg@L7TQhIetgCxGp/05n1iG2055m9N68eW@83rmjq7LDY1mbF58X5/vZucRsHgGl3btS7TGDSjJCnOoGvzAq2RKWLdrijrDo4sJUfl8wdSK89SlgrU4wuGOGy0ZjjgN16BUnqPoKYCOxegiQ4@cnBFDK4QscvmLBdcEGr5qbHQNqy82WmyXX5YV50viG/NOeH//srXqIaEbdzDnHy3ibEselZhOJoXYMi1MsiNirJ0ZiRha6Kz8wuu6f53hopeSQbW8U4agVG/EhhDtWbgi74G/ALyQOIs50R9X2Gn/Ybo597@MNov@d7nlVwu/EBvJbHNJ37iPQ6/vZGYeJucZRh14z@cvVD/bhrfR1JNZXV/DnuqjqkHE2R@ZfKv9c2Gf/W1lr75XT4Z86Cnm0tV89nopcjbTWUSRClSTmhgYpIflOQylmYkdkbhrk1o7TVF8mp3ZITN@GsSmZ0IxpGOSGZ0XXjg@avUMaNcvMtdRrMuMAD8iwsh2f0KTxp@nFIACTZuv5Lw)

### How?

#### Method

For each pair of points \$(A,B)\$, we generate the circle \$(X,Y,r)\$ whose diameter is \$AB\$.

$$X=\frac{A_x+B_x}{2},\;Y=\frac{A_y+B_y}{2},\;r=\sqrt{\left(\frac{A_x-B_x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A_y-B_y}{2}\right)^2}$$

For each triple of distinct points \$(A,B,C)\$, we generate the circle \$(X,Y,r)\$ which circumscribes the triangle \$ABC\$.

$$d=A_x(B_y-C_y)+B_x(C_y-A_y)+C_x(A_y-B_y)$$
$$X=\frac{({A_x}^2+{A_y}^2)(B_y-C_y)+({B_x}^2+{B_y}^2)(C_y-A_y)+({C_x}^2+{C_y}^2)(A_y-B_y)}{2d}$$
$$Y=\frac{({A_x}^2+{A_y}^2)(C_x-B_x)+({B_x}^2+{B_y}^2)(A_x-C_x)+({C_x}^2+{C_y}^2)(B_x-A_x)}{2d}$$
$$r=\sqrt{(X-A_x)^2+(Y-A_y)^2}$$

For each generated circle, we test whether each point \$(x,y)\$ is enclosed within it:

$$\sqrt{(x-X)^2+(y-Y)^2}\le r$$

And we eventually return the smallest valid circle.

#### Implementation

In the JS code, the formula to compute \$(X,Y)\$ for the triangle's circumscribed circle is slightly simplified. Assuming \$d\neq0\$, we define \$q={C_x}^2+{C_y}^2\$, leading to:

$$X=\frac{({A_x}^2+{A_y}^2-q)(B_y-C_y)+({B_x}^2+{B_y}^2-q)(C_y-A_y)}{2d}$$
$$Y=\frac{({A_x}^2+{A_y}^2-q)(C_x-B_x)+({B_x}^2+{B_y}^2-q)(A_x-C_x)}{2d}$$

This way, the helper function \$F\$ requires only two parameters \$(j,k)\$ to compute each coordinate:

- \$(B_y-C_y,\;C_y-A_y)\$ for \$X\$
- \$(C_x-B_x,\;A_x-C_x)\$ for \$Y\$

The third parameter used in \$F\$ (i.e. its actual argument \$s\$) is used to compute \$(X,Y)\$ when \$d=0\$, meaning that the triangle is degenerate and we have to try to use the diameter instead.

Comment: maybe writing a Newton-type numerical optimizer is shorter...

Comment: Do you have a proof of correctness? I can see that this is a plausible approach, but more than that seems to require quite a bit of work.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The algorithm is mentioned on Wikipedia: _a naive algorithm solves the problem in time O(n^4) by testing the circles determined by all pairs and triples of points_. But unfortunately, there's no link to a proof.

Comment: Will it meet problem of precision making there no solution?

Comment: @l4m2 I suppose it could happen. But I think that [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14459/58563) applies in that case.

Comment: @Arnauld If you need some strange numbers to reach, I may say that's fine; If it even fail in easy situation that may be a problem

Answer (score 14):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

```r
function(x)nlm(function(y)max(Mod(x-y%*%c(1,1i))),0:1)[1:2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5NCoMwEAXgfU@RjZA0GcmkGn@gR@gJSheiCIJGsRX09OnEQikFNy88yDczs2/Zlfl2cfWrGx1fhesH/q2bGKqV38aGr7BF56jmqLATQihdorhjaR7@WU1Tv/GW1xxyqTvFLhIpwcYG8r0WcUpIsXlcXKOYEacflMVIX4sgMghPKjFMAVLkD51WDKUJ8yGhTCClRA2ED42Vdr9MZp91odn/Jf4N)

Takes input as a vector of complex coordinates. `Mod` is the distance (modulus) in the complex plane and `nlm` is an optimization function: it finds the position of the center (output as `estimate`) which minimizes the maximum distance to the input points, and gives the corresponding distance (output as `minimum`), i.e. the radius. Accurate to 3-6 digits; the TIO footer rounds the output to 2 digits.

`nlm` takes a numeric vector as input: the `y%*%c(1,1i)` business converts it to a complex.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>100</s> 98 bytes

```
_²§½
1ịṭƊZIṚṙ€1N1¦,@ṭ@²§$µḢZḢ×Ø1œị$SḤ÷@P§
ZṀ+ṂHƲ€_@Ç+ḷʋ⁸,_²§½ʋḢ¥¥
œc3Ç€;ŒcZÆm,Hñ/$Ʋ€$ñ_ƭƒⱮṀ¥Ðḟ⁸ṚÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@0KZDyw/t5TJ8uLv74c61x7qiPB/unPVw58xHTWsM/QwPLdNxAAo7gFSpHNr6cMeiKCA@PP3wDMOjk4FaVIIf7lhyeLtDwKHlXFEPdzZoP9zZ5HFsE1BzvMPhdu2HO7af6n7UuEMHas2pbqDuQ0sPLeU6OjnZ@HA7UJ310UnJUYfbcnU8Dm/UVwFrVTm8Mf7Y2mOTHm1cBzTy0NLDEx7umA80Beiww/OABvz//z9aw0DHQFNHQcNQxwhEGevomoBoEx1dU7CwgY6uoYFmLAA)

In contrast to [my Wolfram language answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187318/42248), Jelly needs quite a lot of code to achieve this (unless I’m missing something!). This full program takes the list of points as its argument and returns the centre and radius of the smallest enclosing circle. It generates circumcircles for all sets of three points, and diameters for all sets of two points, checks which include all of the points and then picks the one with the smallest radius.

Code for the make_circumcircle bit was inspired by code at [this site](https://www.nayuki.io/res/smallest-enclosing-circle/smallestenclosingcircle.py), in turn inspired by Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't understand this code, but rather than diameters and circumcircles separately, could you generate all sets of three points with duplicates and filter out the lists of three identical points?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>244</s> 242 bytes

```python
P={complex(*p)for p in input()}
Z=9e999,
for p in P:
 for q in{p}^P:
	for r in{p}^P:R,S=1j*(p-q),q-r;C=S.imag and S.real/S.imag-1jor 1;c=(p+q-(S and(C*(p-r)).real/(C*R).real*R))/2;Z=min(Z,(max(abs(c-t)for t in P),c.imag,c.real))
print Z[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RasMwDEWfl6/wo9RZ6VzoWif4qT9QmreUDrIs61IaR/E8aCj99sxJoCDQPdK9Qtz7n9auiHvuh2Fv7mXb8LW6wYLxu3WCRW1D8Z8HfES50ZXWWkbP1T6JxAhdgDs/PgK/jOyefJCZUZcFMHUoO3LpzmRx3RRnUdgvkcWuKq7LeULqEqIqLQ3wa0eQjRbYjVmHODsDHmYZOi5XaW6a2kIuoSluUHz@Qkl@et1P/6Esp9uhjSHEiF1tvciPSULqNAxH2MRK0nusUQqgjaRJrKV6mwY6Xkva4ukf)

This uses the brute-force O(n^4) algorithm, iterating through each pair and triangle of points, calculating the centre, and keeping the centre that needs the smallest radius to enclose all points. It calculates the circumcentre of 3 points via finding the intersection of two perpendicular bisectors (or, if two points are equal it uses the midpoint with the third).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Since you are using Python 2, you can save 1 byte by converting the two spaces on the 5th line to a tab.

Comment: `P={x+y*1j for x,y in input()}` saves 2 bytes as well.

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 348 chars, 696 bytes

```
f←{h←{0=k←⍺-1:,¨⍵⋄(k<0)∨k≥i←≢w←⍵:⍬⋄↑,/{w[⍵],¨k h w[(⍳i)∼⍳⍵]}¨⍳i-k}⋄1≥≡⍵:⍺h⍵⋄⍺h⊂¨⍵}
c←{⍵≡⍬:1⋄(x r)←⍵⋄(-r*2)++/2*⍨⍺-x}
p←{(b k)←⍺ ⍵⋄∧/¨1e¯13≥{{⍵{⍵c⍺}¨b}k[⍵]}¨⍳≢k}
s2←{(+/k),√+/↑2*⍨-/k←2÷⍨⍵}
s3←{0=d←2×-.×m←⊃{⍵,1}¨⍵:⍬⋄m[;1]←{+/2*⍨⍵}¨⍵⋄x←d÷⍨-.×m⋄m[;2]←{1⊃⍵}¨⍵⋄y←d÷⍨--.×m⋄(⊂x y),√+/2*⍨(x y)-1⊃⍵}
s←{v/⍨⍵p v←(s2¨2 f⍵)∪s3¨3 f⍵}
s1←{↑v/⍨sn=⌊/sn←{2⊃⍵}¨v←s⍵}
```

This is one 'implementation' of formulas in Arnauld solution...Results and comments:

```
  s1 (¯8 0)(3 1)(¯6.2 ¯8)(3 9.5)
¯1.6 0.75  9.885469134 
  s1 (7.1 ¯6.9)(¯7 ¯9)(5 10)(¯9.5 ¯8)
¯1.732305109 0.5829680042  11.57602798 
  s1 (0 0)(1 2)(3 ¯4)(4 ¯5)(10 ¯10)
5.5 ¯4  7.5 
  s1 (6 6)(¯6 7)(¯7 ¯6)(6 ¯8)
0 ¯0.5  9.604686356 
  s1 (6 6)(¯6 7)(¯7 ¯6)(6 ¯8)(0 0)(1 2)(3 ¯4)(4 ¯5)(10 ¯10)
2 ¯1.5  11.67261753 
  s1 (6 6)(¯6 7)(¯7 ¯6)(6 ¯8)(1 2)(3 ¯4)(4 ¯5)(10 ¯10)(7.1 ¯6.9)(¯7 ¯9)(5 10)(¯9.5 ¯8)
1.006578947 ¯1.623355263  12.29023186 
  s1 (1 1)(2 2)(3 3)(4 4)
2.5 2.5  2.121320344 
  ⎕fmt s3 (1 1)(2 2)(3 3)(4 4)
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
```

f: finds the combination of alpha ojets in the omega set

```
f←{h←{0=k←⍺-1:,¨⍵⋄(k<0)∨k≥i←≢w←⍵:⍬⋄↑,/{w[⍵],¨k h w[(⍳i)∼⍳⍵]}¨⍳i-k}⋄1≥≡⍵:⍺h⍵⋄⍺h⊂¨⍵}
```

((X,Y), r) from now represent one circonference of radius r and center in (X Y).

c: finds if the point in ⍺ is inside the circumference ((X Y) r) in ⍵ (result <=0) ot it is external (result >0)
In the case of circumference input in ⍵ it is ⍬ as input, it would return 1 (out of circumference)
each possible input in ⍺.

```
c←{⍵≡⍬:1⋄(x r)←⍵⋄(-r*2)++/2*⍨⍺-x}
```

p: if ⍵ is an array of ((X Y) r); for each of the ((X Y) r) in ⍵
writes 1 if all points in the array ⍺ are internal to ((X Y) r) otherwise writes 0
NB Here's something that do not goes because I had to round to epsilon= 1e¯13.
in other words in limit cases of points in the plane (and probably built on purpose)
it is not 100% solution insured

```
p←{(b k)←⍺ ⍵⋄∧/¨1e¯13≥{{⍵{⍵c⍺}¨b}k[⍵]}¨⍳≢k}
```

s2: from 2-point in ⍵, it returns the circumference in the format ((X Y) r)
that has diameter in those 2 points

```
s2←{(+/k),√+/↑2*⍨-/k←2÷⍨⍵}
```

s3: from 3 points it return the circumference in the format ((X Y) r) passing through those three points
If there are problems (for example points are aligned), it would fail and return ⍬.

```
s3←{0=d←2×-.×m←⊃{⍵,1}¨⍵:⍬⋄m[;1]←{+/2*⍨⍵}¨⍵⋄x←d÷⍨-.×m⋄m[;2]←{1⊃⍵}¨⍵⋄y←d÷⍨--.×m⋄(⊂x y),√+/2*⍨(x y)-1⊃⍵}
```

note that -.× find the determinant of a matrix nxn and

```
  ⎕fmt ⊃{⍵,1}¨(¯8 0)(3 1)(¯6.2 ¯8)
┌3─────────┐     
3 ¯8    0 1│     |ax  ay 1|
│  3    1 1│   d=|bx  by 1|=ax(by-cy)-bx(ay-cy)+cx(ay-by)=ax(by-cy)+bx(cy-ay)+cx(ay-by)
│ ¯6.2 ¯8 1│     |cx  cy 1|
└~─────────┘
```

s: from n points in ⍵, it finds the type circumferences of those found by s2 or those of type s3
that contain all n points.

```
s←{v/⍨⍵p v←(s2¨2 f⍵)∪s3¨3 f⍵}
```

s1: from the set found from the s above calculates those that have minimum radius and returns
the first one that has minimal radius. The three numbers as arrays
(the first and second coordinates are the coordinates of the center, while the third is the
radius of the circumference found).

```
s1←{↑v/⍨sn=⌊/sn←{2⊃⍵}¨v←s⍵}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) <s>212</s> 190 bytes

This solution is incorrect, and I have to work now so I do not have time to fix it.

```
a=eval(input())
b=lambda a,b: ((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)**.5
c=0
d=1
for e in a:
    for f in a:
        g=b(e,f)
        if g>c:
            c=g
            d=[e,f]
print(((d[0][0]+d[1][0])/2,(d[0][1]+d[1][1])/2,c/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCoMwEEXX5iuynNj4SMRihfRHxEVijA1YFbGFfr2daAvzOmcWd/lsj3kq9l2r/q1H8NPy2oAxYtSon8ZqqrmpKYBu8jYxOFgcywuiCCgOxE5L0qmcWCWIm1faUz9RXZMogPtDNCgDPXcMT@/ocO@CjDo1hGVVg7@WLKufNgCwGIZ1sZgScjPJTyd@ThyuyyRj@95AUvGccQoFF2El11TypDrNLS1Z@wU)

I figured out which two points are furthest and then I generated an equation for a circle based off those points!

I know this isn't the shortest in python, but it's the best I could do! Also this is my first attempt at doing one of these, so please be understanding!

Comment: This can be golfed some more. For example, you can shorten `if g>c:\n c=g\n d=[e,f]` to `if g>c:c=g;d=[e,f]`, saving you a lot of whitespace. I don't think you need to initialise d beforehand, also using two variables and `E,F=e,f` in line 10 will make your `print` a lot shorter.  I think a solution with `max` and a list comprehension would be even shorter than two loops, but I might be wrong.
Sadly, however, your solution is not correct. For the points (-1,0), (0,1.41), (0.5, 0), (1,0) your solution computes a circle around 0 with radius 1. But the point (1, 1.41) is not in that circle.

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for your answer. As pointed in the comment above, your solution is not correct. A hint for brute-force solution: The smallest possible circle touches either two points or three points. You can start calculating the equation for the circle that touches each pair of points and check if there's one that encloses all points. Then calculate the equation for the circle that touches each triplet of points and check if there's one that encloses all points. Once you get all the possible circles, select the one with the smallest radius.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna try to make it work, and then I will update the answer. I need to figure out how to check if a point is contained in a circle.

Comment: Once you have the center and radius of the circle, check if the distance between the center and each point is less than or equal to the radius; if that condition is true for all points, that circle is a candidate